# How to display large text in Processing?

Tags: processing

I am trying to draw a single very large-size character (such as number"3"and char"A") on screen in Processing. Ideally, the height of the character will be just slightly less than the screen height.

I've tried :

1. go to Tools, then Create font. However the biggest font size I am able to create is 250.
2. use `textSize(360);`  before draw text on screen. However its still not big enough and the word is blurred.

Has anyone done something like this before? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're resizing a font whose size was defined using the *IDE create font tool*. Instead of **loadFont()**, you could use the **[createFont()](http://processing.org/reference/createFont_.html)** function, which is used to create a font from one of the built-in typefaces (*Serif, SansSerif, Monospaced, Dialog, DialogInput*) that map to the default fonts on each operating system.

> One advantage of using createFont () is that the text will look smooth
>   at any size, unlinke a font used with loadFont (), which may be
>   distorted as it is resized. It's possibile to use createFont () to
>   specify something besides a built-in font, but there's no guarantee
>   that the font will be installed on another's user system. – [Ben Fry, Visualizing Data](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596514556.do)

The following code displays "p5" on the screen:

```
PFont font;

void setup () {
size(500,500);
font = createFont ("Serif",height);
textFont (font);
}

void draw () {
background(255);  
fill(0);
textAlign(CENTER,CENTER);
text("p5",width/2,height/2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer is perfect! I've tried it, the code works very well!